# ibus Avro in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ibus-avro

I used the instructions given [here](http://linux.omicronlab.com/ubuntu_14.04.html) to install ibus Avro in my ubuntu 14.04 LTS (64 bit) but ibus avro was not installed. Can anyone help me to solve this case? After giving the commands in terminal nothing happens.

Answer (score 3):

### Installation

Open Terminal and enter the following commands one by one.

1. Add `ibus-avro` repository

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/sarimkhan/xUbuntu_14.04/ ./"
   ```
2. Add key

   ```
   wget -q http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/sarimkhan/xUbuntu_14.04/Release.key -O- | sudo apt-key add -
   ```
3. Update package list

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. Install `ibus-avro`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ibus-avro-trusty
   ```
5. Now you need to logout and login again or restart your computer.

### Using `ibus-avro`

1. Click the IM icon in menubar and Select Text Entry Setting
2. In *Text Entry Setting* window click + icon (marked by arrow) in left pane. Write avro in the search box (marked by arrow). Choose Bengali (Avro Phonetic) from the list and press Add button to add Avro to the list.
3. (Optional) The keyboard shortcut to switch input method has been changed to Super+Space since Ubuntu 13.10. You can change it to your preference from Text Entry Setting window.
4. Open any text editing software (like, gedit). Now Press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to toggle between English and Avro (Bengali)
5. Enjoy Avro

Comment: I did each and every step correctly. But still switching between the languages, it's not updating.

Answer (score 0):

Installation

Please run these commands from the terminal. Never forget to be in relevant directory.

```
wget "https://github.com/maateen/avro/releases/download/v2.0/avro_2.0-1_all.deb"

sudo dpkg -i avro_2.0-1_all.deb
```

If you get any dependency error, then also run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

I hope, all is well now and the installation has been finished.

Now go to System Settings -> Keyboard -> Text Entry.

Search and add Avro Phonetic as input source.

That's all.